# RabbitMQ cluster fails when one node is not reachable

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, seneca

I created a RabbitMQ cluster via Docker and Docker Cloud. I am running two RabbitMQ container on two separate nodes (both hosted on AWS).

The output of `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` is:

```
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-2' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-1','rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-2']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-1','rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-2']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-1">>},
 {partitions,[]}]
```

However, when I am stopping one container/node, then my messages cannot get delievered and get queued in `.dlx`

*I am using senecajs with NodeJS.*

Did anybody have the same problems and can point me into a direction?

Comment: do you use HA queues ? https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

> The problem was that Docker, after starting, caches the DNS and is not
>   able to connect to a new one. So if one cluster fails, Docker still
>   tries to connect to the one, instead of trying a new one.

The solution was to write my own function when connecting to the RabbitMQ. I first check with [net.createConnection](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectlistener) if the host is online. If yes, I connect to it, if not I try a different one.

**Every time a RabbitMQ node is down, my service fails, restarts and calls the "try this host" function.**